# Why are types with no data constructors valid?

Tags: haskell

This seems to be legal:

```
data MagazineInfo = Int String
    deriving (Show)
```

I am not sure if there is a default data constructor, but the above code compiles.

Why is the above valid Haskell, since I did not explicitly specify a value constructor?

Comment: If you would have tried using this datatype by writing a selector, you would have noticed that there is no `Int` you could get out...

Answer (score 29):

You do have a data constructor there--it's `Int`. Type names live in a separate namespace from data constructors, which is why you don't get an error even though there happens to be a type also named `Int`.

Comment: And it's common for the data constructor name to be the same as the type name in cases, like this, where there is only one construtor. `data MagazineInfo = MagazineInfo String`

Comment: There is also, however, such a thing as [empty types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Empty_type)—but indeed the poster's example isn't one.  Empty types are used in combination with some advanced type system techniques.

Comment: Of course, for the single-constructor, single-item cases, `newtype` is preferred over `data`.

Comment: @DanBurton: Unless you want a distinguished ⊥.